# Finding the first occurrence of a substring in a string- what is the time complexity of using three pointers and incrementing at each character match?

Tags: python, string, time-complexity

We are given a `long string s`, and a `shorter string t`.

e.g. `t = "aaaab"`, `s = "aaaaaaaaaaaab"`

We want to find the **first instance** where **t appears in s**, and if it doesn't then simply `return -1`.

My idea is to initiate `three pointers` starting at 0; using two of the pointers (one pointing at the start of t and the other at start of s), I will compare if the characters that both pointers are pointing at, and if they match, I will increment both pointers. If they don't match, I will move the pointer at t backwards, to point at the character one ahead of the third pointer. (i.e. the third pointer is used to keep track of the last character we checked as the potential solution).

My question is, would the above run in a time complexity of `O(m + n)` or `O(mn)` ? I would assume `O(mn)`, since we are potentially iterating through the whole of string t for every character of s?

If this is true, in what instance would we get `O(m+n)`? And is this possible, as I read that it is possible though I don't have the solution.

Comment: I'm guessing your question is more about the complexity... but just want to check before you may end up writing something from scratch unnecessarily, you are aware that [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) exists?

Comment: Hi Jon, yes the question was intended for the purpose of only time complexity. I was aware of str.find but wanted a more algorithmic way to solve the problem- as though I was asked it in an interview!

Comment: Probably best to have a read through the most common algorithms used at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm

Comment: Thanks Jon, I didn't know this was a common exercise. Will read through the Wiki page.

Comment: Worst case would be O(mn) if you are searching for string of length *n* in a string of length *m* that only contains repeated partial matches.  e.g. searching "aaad" in "aaaaaaaaaa". but in most cases it would be closer to O(m+n)

Comment: Thanks Alain, this does make sense! - especially the special case that you mentioned.